# tinymce editor in Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, tinymce

I am trying to embed the TinyMCE editor in an Angular2 web app using the instructions found here: https://www.tinymce.com/docs/integrations/angular2/.

First I got the error - "cannot find name tinymce".
I have then added "*tinymce: any;*" to the component - only to get the error "*Cannot read property 'init' of undefined*"

I have also added the scripts in the angular-cli.json and declared the variable i typings.d.ts file - what am I missing here ?

```
import {
    Component,
    OnDestroy,
    AfterViewInit,
    EventEmitter,
    Input,
    Output
} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'simple-tiny',
    template: `<textarea id="{{elementId}}"></textarea>`
})
export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit, OnDestroy {
  title = 'app works!';
  @Input() elementId: String;
  @Output() onEditorKeyup = new EventEmitter<any>();

  editor;
  tinymce: any;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
      this.tinymce.init({
          selector: '#' + this.elementId,
          plugins: ['link', 'paste', 'table'],
          skin_url: 'assets/skins/lightgray',
          setup: editor => {
              this.editor = editor;
              editor.on('keyup', () => {
                  const content = editor.getContent();
                  this.onEditorKeyup.emit(content);
              });
          },
      });
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
      this.tinymce.remove(this.editor);
  }
}
```

Regards
Morten Nieslen

Comment: Maybe your typings file isn't being read. Try to declare it in the component class. And get rid the variable inside the class.

Comment: sorry if this is a stupid question - but how do you do that? (I'm quite new to Angular)

Comment: `declare var tinymce: any;`. Add that before the `@Component`

Comment: Thank's for you help, it is working now

Comment: I did that and it compiled but now it says `Uncaught ReferenceError: tinymce is not defined.`

Answer (score 0):

Replace with this code , it should work.You need to declare tinymce outside class.

```
import {
  Component,
  OnDestroy,
  AfterViewInit,
  EventEmitter,
  Input,
  Output
} from '@angular/core';

 declare const tinymce: any;

@Component({
  selector: 'simple-tiny',
  template: `<textarea id="{{elementId}}"></textarea>`
})
export class guiEditorComponent implements AfterViewInit, OnDestroy {
  @Input() elementId: String;
  @Output() onEditorKeyup = new EventEmitter<any>();
  editor;


  constructor()
  {

  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    tinymce.init({
      selector: '#' + this.elementId,
      plugins: ['advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview anchor',
                    'searchreplace visualblocks code fullscreen',
                    'insertdatetime media table contextmenu paste code'],
      skin_url: 'assets/skins/lightgray',
      setup: editor => {
        this.editor = editor;
        editor.on('keyup', () => {
          const content = editor.getContent();
          this.onEditorKeyup.emit(content);
        });
      },
    });
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    tinymce.remove(this.editor);
  }
}
```

Comment: This fix is not working. Even thought the official page says so. Can you please help.

Answer (score 0):

I resolve these errors by adding the typings.d.ts file to the includes of tsconfig.app.json file :

```
"include": [
    "src/*.ts",
    "src/**/*.ts",
    "src/**/*.d.ts",
    "typings.d.ts",
    "../node_modules/@nebular/**/*.ts"
  ]
```